# Django on GAE - without cloud SQL

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Is it possible to use google app engine to host django app without being billed for database use?

I see from documentation that sqlite isn't, and using mysql doesn't work for me.

Is there a way to use a backend that isn't Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Use django-nonrel which uses the HRD

http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/